# CSS template not applying to my page

Tags: html, css

I am making a blog-type page to practice some web.py. I made a rough html file and I tried to apply a CSS bootstrapper/template but it is not working for me anymore. This is the HTML of the home page, in essence.

`
                
                      Home Feed

Profile

Messages

Friends

Communities

```
                <li><a href="#"><span class="mdi mdi-bell"> </span> Notifications</a></li>
                <li class="seperator"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="mdi mdi-settings"> </span> Settings</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span class="mdi mdi-help-circle"> </span> Help</a></li>

            </ul>
        <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="post-box">
            <form id="post-activity">
                <textarea name="content" class="post-input" placeholder="What's new, $session['user']['name']?"></textarea>
                <button id="post-button" class="btn btn-info btn-raised waves-effect" type="submit"><span class="mdi mdi-send"></span> Post</button>
            </form>
        </div>

            <div class="post-card">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="avatar"></div>
                    <a href="/profile">Adrian Bernat</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Test Content
                </div>
                <div class="footer">

                    <button class="btn btn-round waves-effect btn-default btn-raised btn-like"><span class="mdi mdi-thumb-up-outline"></span> Like</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-round waves-effect btn-default btn-raised btn-comment"><span class="mdi mdi-comment-text-outline"></span> Comment</button>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

I'm not sure that pasted correctly, but the  should apply those CSS profiles that I have, but when I run the cope, the HTML shows up raw and un-styled. Does anyone know why?

EDIT: [here](https://ibb.co/h8Uh5F) is what I am getting, and [here](https://ibb.co/ewjtCv) is what it SHOULD look like.

Comment: did you include the Bootstrap style sheet with your html?

Answer (score 0):

Did you **make sure to include the CSS files for bootstrap**?

Even if you give the html elements bootstrap classes you still **need** to load bootstrap in order for the styling to work.

In the example below I loaded bootstrap using this:

```
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

You may or may not want to do the same. 
There many ways to [include bootstrap files with your html](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp).

I didn't edit your html. I only loaded bootstrap at the top.

**Is this what you wanted?**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="mdi mdi-bell"></span> Notifications</a></li>
  <li class="seperator"></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="mdi mdi-settings"></span> Settings</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="mdi mdi-help-circle"></span> Help</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="post-box">
    <form id="post-activity">
      <textarea name="content" class="post-input" placeholder="What's new, $session['user']['name']?"></textarea>
      <button id="post-button" class="btn btn-info btn-raised waves-effect" type="submit"><span class="mdi mdi-send"></span> Post</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="post-card">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
      <a href="/profile">Adrian Bernat</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Test Content
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <button class="btn btn-round waves-effect btn-default btn-raised btn-like"><span class="mdi mdi-thumb-up-outline"></span> Like
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-round waves-effect btn-default btn-raised btn-comment"><span class="mdi mdi-comment-text-outline"></span> Comment
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have the bootstrap included. I have used it for other portions of the HTML and it has worked. I am using web.py to include it; i will link the gist here so you can see. [link](https://gist.github.com/adi105/a574a4c05c05f402b1ea444596ce7107)

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://ibb.co/h8Uh5F) of what the webpage looks like as of right now, and [this](https://ibb.co/ewjtCv) is what it should look like, for reference. I am following a code-along of sorts to learn about web.py. I have identified all of the spans with the correct classes and opening the CSS files show that those class tags are indeed used, so I am not sure why this is happening.